# Pytest-django transaction is not commited to DB physically

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

There is a `conftest.py` file that allows me to use my custom transactional fixture *fake_user*

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
@pytest.fixture
def fake_user():
    user = getattr(fake_user, 'user', None)
    if user is None:
        user_data = dict(
            id=1,
            is_superuser=False,
            is_staff=False,
            email='foo@barmail.com', 
            username='foobaruser',
            password='passwordmaster',
            date_joined=timezone.now()
        )
        user = User.objects.create(
            **user_data
        )
        user.save()
        # pdb.set_trace()
        fake_user.user = user
    yield user
```

Somehow if I debug with pdb.set_trace() the code above, I get `User.objects.all()` equal to `<QuerySet [<User: foobaruser>]>`. However there are no any real test DB records. So when querying "User" objects in another high level function, e.g. "GraphQL" or REST call, I get "Users" table being absolutely empty.
How could I enable real test DB transactions?
Why does't pytest allow any physical records or what prevents them from being inserted?

Comment: Having `transaction=True` flushes the DB between each test, this is probably clearing out the created user, you should probably remove it https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#testing-transactions

Comment: IDK how, but thank, that worked — I used earlier all the test without `transaction=True` but now it is done the right way

Comment: It still doesn't work inside the fixture. Works only if I define and save a user in a final pytest function

Answer (score 0):

Pytest flushes the test database between runs; add `--reuse-db` to your options to retain the data.

Comment: The problem is inside a single run — there are no records in `auth_user` table at all

Answer (score 0):

What really helped me:
This usage of `django_db_blocker`: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#randomize-database-sequences
After inserting the user this way:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def fake_user(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    user = getattr(fake_user, 'user', None)
    if user is None:
        user_data = dict(
            id=1,
            is_superuser=False,
            is_staff=False,
            email='foo@barmail.com', 
            username='foobaruser',
            password='passwordmaster',
            date_joined=timezone.now()
        )
        with django_db_blocker.unblock():
            user = User.objects.create(
                **user_data
            )
        fake_user.user = user
    yield user
```

the data appeared in Postgres.
Thanks!